# Override the ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form which I wanted to overwrite the manytomanyfield 
with a autocomplet widget I prepared.

```
class AutoCompleteForeignKeyWidget(forms.TextInput):
    input_type = 'text'


class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    regions = forms.CharField(widget=AutoCompleteForeignKeyWidget(attrs={
        'class': 'regions', 'placeholder': 'Type Region',
        'autocomplete': 'off'
    }), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        exclude = ('regions')
```

But this is unsucessful. I get an Integrity Error `DETAIL:  Key (region_id)=(0) is not present in table "destinations_region".` Is there a way to override the manytomanyfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this cannot work because the browser will sent the content of the input as form field value.

This means that django will receive region = 'Some region name'. But Django ManyToManyField is meant to work with a list of primary keys, like `[1,2,3]`, where `1` is the PK of the first selected region, and so on.

I recommend that you use an [autocomplete app](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/) which will make it a lot easier.